# Redirect To Another Site With Header Information Attached Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am trying to make a client side click and redirect to another site with header information added, my client side code for the onclick is this:

```
function selectApp(appGUID, userId ,embedUrl)
{
    if(embedUrl==="")
    {
        var success = setAppGUID(appGUID);
        window.location.replace('AppDetail.aspx');
    }
    else
    {   
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: embedUrl,
            contentType: "text/html",
            beforeSend: function (xhr, settings) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("UserId", userId);
            },
            success: function (msg) {
                //actually redirect to the site
                window.location.replace(embedUrl);
            }
        });
    }  
}
```

And the server side code in `embedUrl` is

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string isSet = (String)HttpContext.Current.Session["saveUserID"];
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(isSet))
    {
        NameValueCollection headers = base.Request.Headers;
        for (int i = 0; i < headers.Count; i++)
        {
            if (headers.GetKey(i).Equals("UserId"))
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Session["saveUserID"] = headers.Get(i);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        TextBox1.Text = HttpContext.Current.Session["saveUserID"].ToString();
    }
}
```

This seems to work but it's not too elegant. Is there a way to redirect with header data? Without (what I'm doing) saving header info in a session var then doing a redirect in 2 seperate pieces.

Comment: What about using a cookie instead? Browsers will automatically send cookies to their respective domains. And, a cookie is just a special type of header.

Comment: @Brandon isnt there anyway to do this in one shot get rid of the session variable approach?

Comment: Are you trying to hide user id from the user? You can always encrypt the query string or token.

Comment: Yes I am trying to hide the user but cannot use querystring (even encrypted) as per requirement

Comment: If you use cookies, you don't have to use a session variable at all.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can implement a page method and post data to it. 
Moving your current logic in that method.

See these examples:

- http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/
- http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/jquery_webforms_Post_Data_To_PageMethod.ashx

Upon successful post you can redirect to another page like your current implementation.

**Edit**: Try something like this:

1) Add a Web method in Code behind

```
  [WebMethod]
  public static string SaveUserId(string userId)
  {
    string sessionUserId= (string)HttpContext.Current.Session["saveUserID"];
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sessionUserId))
      HttpContext.Current.Session["saveUserID"] = userId;
    else
      TextBox1.Text = sessionUserId;
  }
```

2) Call it from JS

```
 //Add here code before..
 $.ajax({
                url: "PageName.aspx/SaveUserId",
                data: "{'userid':" + userid + "}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json"
                success: function (msg) {
                    //actually redirect to the site
                    window.location.replace(embedUrl);
                }
            });
```

More on calling Page methods with jQuery:

- http://deebujacob.blogspot.in/2012/01/aspnet-ajax-web-method-call-using.html
- http://www.misfitgeek.com/calling-web-service-page-methods-with-jquery/